# dnsmasq - Multiple forwarding servers for domain entries?

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq

I was wondering if it was possible to configure dnsmasq to send "server=" entries to multiple upstream servers?

so like this:

```
server=/facebook.com/1.2.3.4
server=/facebook.com/2.3.4.5
```

and have it pick which one based on it being available or not, as with `resolv.conf`? According to the man page, it looks like only one is allowed, but I wondered if there was a way to ask it to behave this way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well in your example you're only pointing out facebook, but I guess you would have the same need for every hostname you might visit

dnsmasq provides the option --all-servers

> **--all-servers**
>
> By  default,  when  dnsmasq has more than one upstream server available, it will send queries to just one server. Setting
>   this flag forces dnsmasq to send all queries to all available servers.
>                 The reply from the server which answers first will be returned to the original requestor.

Set a several DNS servers

```
server=OpenDNS.IP.Addr.ess

server=GoogleDNS.IP.Addr.ess

server=...
```

And the fastest response will be considered

Answer (score 10):

Sure just add multiple lines.

```
server=/facebook.com/1.2.3.4
server=/facebook.com/2.3.4.5
```

Man dnsmasq

```
   -S, --server=[/[<domain>]/[domain/]] ...
          ...  More than one -S  flag  is  allowed,  with
          repeated domain or ipaddr parts as required.
```

Comment: huh.... but is the behavior as per resolv.conf?

Comment: yes, if one the first server is unavailable, dnsmasq will then send the request to the second server (unless the --all-servers options is used, that will force dnsmasq to use all the servers in parallel and take the first reply)